# Process files by custom Grunt task

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, gruntjs

I am new to grunt... I just tried to implement a custom task (using `TypeScript`) that shall iterate over a set of given files and do some processing. This is what I have so far...

```
function gruntFile(grunt: IGrunt): void {
    grunt.registerMultiTask("custom", "...", () => {
        this.files.forEach(function(next) {
            ...
        });
    });

    var config: grunt.config.IProjectConfig = {
        custom: {
            files: [ 
                "folder1/*.json", 
                "folder2/**/*.json"
            ]
        }
    };
    grunt.initConfig(config);
}
(module).exports = gruntFile;
```

Currently I struggle with the configuration and how I can acccess the files array in my custom task handler function. Grunt gives me the error that it cannot read the property `forEach` of undefined. I also tried a configuration that looks like that...

```
var config = {
    custom: {
        files : [
            { src: "folder1/*.json" },
            { src: "folder2/**/*.json" }
        ]
    }
};
```

Not sure about that, but I have seen that in some tutorials...

I have seen a couple of sample grunt-files already, but in each example the configuration looks a bit different, or files are used in conjunction with imported tasks and modules, so the samples do not show how the configured files are accessed. Any guidance that helps me to better understand how it works (and what I am doing wrong) is appreciated.

**Update**

I found out that I can query options via the config-property, but I am not sure if this is the right way to do it. In my task-handler I do this to query the list of configured files...

```
var files = grunt.config.get("custom.files");
```

...which returns the expected array (but I find it a bit odd to query options via a path expression). I realized that (by using `TypeScript`) the scope of `this` is not the context of the current task; that is the reason why `files` was always undefined. Changing the call to `registerMutliTask` to...

```
grunt.registerMultiTask("custom", "...", function() { ... });
```

...fixed this problem. I use wildcard characters in the path-expression; I was hoping that Grunt can expand those expressions and give me a list of all matching paths. Does this functionality exist, or do I have to create that on my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to iterate over the configured files (file pattern) by using the following code...

```
grunt.registerMultiTask("custom", "...", function() {
    grunt.file
        .expand(this.data)
        .forEach(function(file) {
            ...
        });
});
```